# Equation for logarithmic and exponential equation

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I've tried to solve this by graphing, inversing the two functions, but I just can't really get the exact value.

$3^x=-\log_3{x}$

Comment: This equation does not have a closed form ("exact") solution. A numerical approximation is the best you can do.

Comment: You won't be able to find the answer analytically. You'll have to use numerical methods.

Comment: by a numerical method we get

Comment: $$x\approx 0.239487731486134739191$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, only numerical methods would solve the problem.

By inspection, you can see that the solution is "close" to $\frac 14$. If you make a Taylor expansion around this point or (it is the same), one iteration of Newton method, you should get 
$$x\approx \frac 14+ \frac{\log (4)-\sqrt[4]{3} \log (3)}{4+\sqrt[4]{3} \log ^2(3)}\approx 0.239342$$ In fact, if we look at the successive iterates, we get 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.25000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.23934214476240469666 \\
 2 & 0.23948770249429066233 \\
 3 & 0.23948773148613359008 \\
 4 & 0.23948773148613473919
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do you mean the following equation?
$$x^3=\log_x3$$

This equation has a nice unique root: $\sqrt[3]3$.